# For loop for VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tried this:

```
get_choices: function (item, index){
    console.log(item)
},

this.questions.forEach(this.get_choices())
```

But it says

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.questions.forEach is not a function"
```

I also tried:

```
for(question in this.questions){
    console.log(question)
}
```

But it didn't output anything, it didn't also displayed any error.
Any help? Thanks a lot!

UPDATE:

Here's the `this.questions`. It is an array of objects:

```
data: {
    questions: [
        {'name': 'etc', 'content': 'etc'},
        {'name': 'etc2', 'content': 'etc2'},
    ],
},
```

Comment: What is `this.questions`? It doesn't appear to be an array or anything foreachable.

Comment: You should pass the function instead of calling it: `this.questions.forEach(this.get_choices)`

Comment: @HaoWu `forEach` isn't recognised as a method that exists on `this.questions`. Passing the function reference wouldn't help with that problem.

Comment: @HaoWu Yes I tried it but the same error.

Comment: @VLAZ You're right, on top of that... Make sure `this.questions` is an array and then pass the function as I mentioned

Comment: Your `questions` property contains syntactically invalid code.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm sorry. I changed it to an array now it outputs `undefined` from the `console.log(item)`?

Comment: If you have an array, you have to pass a function reference as @HaoWu said: `this.questions.forEach(this.get_choices)` otherwise you are just calling the function once with no input.

Comment: Please, don't truncate things unless you're sure there are irrelevant. Where are `get_choices:`  and `this.questions.forEach` used exactly? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the paranthesis from your function call, you just need the reference

```
this.questions.forEach(this.get_choices)
```

Comment: This is the correct cause of the question problem. In addition, I would also note that you must have your data as a function return an object. The reason is the vue reactivity system. `data() { return { questions: [ /* ... */ ]}}`

Comment: @ChopTRAN well it isnt necessery a must if you use CDN and have no components, but yea its always better to use it as a function https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the object to function as

```
this.questions.forEach((item , index) =>{
      this.get_choices(item , index)
 })
```

or you can also do like

```
this.questions.forEach(this.get_choices)
```